# Python: Wait for asynchronous callback to finish

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, tws

I am currently working with the [TWS Brokerage API](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/md_request.html#gsc.tab=0)

For requesting market data, they have asynchronous function calls. So for example to get the data for a stock you would call reqMKtData(..) as below.

```
self.reqMktData(1003, ContractSamples.AAPLStock(), "", False, False, [])
```

Then you would asynchronously receive the price data with another function called tickPrice.

```
def tickPrice(self, reqId: TickerId, tickType: TickType, price: float, attrib: TickAttrib):
    super().tickPrice(reqId, tickType, price, attrib)
    print("Tick Price. Ticker Id:", reqId, "tickType:", tickType, "Price:", price, "CanAutoExecute:", attrib.canAutoExecute, "PastLimit", attrib.pastLimit)
```

I want to call reqMktData and then have the stock price available on the next line of code. How would I do this?

```
self.reqMktData(1003, ContractSamples.AAPLStock(), "", False, False, [])
aaplPrice = # Wait for tickPrice to execute, then assign the price value from tickPrice to aaplPrice
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up doing a workaround by getting market data from a separate API which was easier to use.